# AWS NLB ignores interval setting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I've recently been playing around with the new network load balancers in AWS. 
I eventually got it working, but it seems the target group health check ignores the interval setting. 
It's an HTTP check set at 30 seconds, but in my web server logs, I see about 3 checks per second. 
Weirdly, in the monitoring graph, it shows checks happening once per second!?

It's not necessarily a problem, but it is rather inefficient.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 1):

I have observed the same thing and posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135471/nlb-target-group-health-checks-are-out-of-control/48168516#48168516) about it. I believe it's normal behaviour for NLBs and the documentation is wrong. It has to be either that, or the documentation is right and the service is operating incorrectly. However when you try to edit the health check manually in the console, the interval options are greyed out and set to 30s (even though it's wildly wrong), so it would seem that they don't want users to be able to control it.