# Is there a way to use NLB to load balance HTTP requests for PHP-FPM + NGINX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

So far, I have been using PHP-FPM + Nginx on ECS with Application Load Balancer, and it's working. The problem is using ALB we cannot use static IP address, this problem is solved if I use NLB instead of ALB.

But it seems NLB only use TCP protocol, and cannot load balance HTTP protocol. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ALB we cannot use static IP address

If you want static public IP for your ALB, you can enable [AWS Global Accelerator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/global-accelerator/latest/dg/what-is-global-accelerator.html):

> Using an accelerator **provides static IP addresses** and improves the availability and performance of your applications.

ALB supports the accelerator:

- [AWS Global Accelerator Now Supports Client IP Address Preservation for Application Load Balancer Endpoints](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/aws-global-accelerator-now-supports-client-ip-address-preservation-for-application-load-balancer-endpoints/)

Answer (score 2):

NLB is low level and does not know you are balancing HTTP when a request arrives : From NLB point of view it is just a TCP request. One solution is to use another ALB after your NLB if you can't do the redirection in nginx.
So the flow of the request will be :

`Your User ---> NLB ---> ALB --> ...`

Comment: This is good idea. I thought about it as well, but using NLB between Users and ALB somehow blow up (increased from 5 each minute to 1000) the number of new connection for ALB. I guess this is because of the health check from NLB which cannot be disabled.

Comment: Yes your Guess is right It is because of HealthCheck @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135471/nlb-target-group-health-checks-are-out-of-control